# PHP Unique Random Numbers

Tags: php

What would be a good way to generate 7 unique random numbers between 1 and 10.
I can't have any duplicates.
I could write a chunk of PHP to do this (using rand() and pushing used numbers onto an array) but there must be a quick way to do it.

any advice would be great.

Comment: Your method is probably fine. Using [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) will speed things up a bit, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple one-liner:

```
print_r(array_rand(array_fill(1, 10, true), 7));
```

Comment: I voted up this, **but** generated array is not random enough, the sequence of elements is regular !

Comment: @Masoud M. Do you have any reference? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.ideone.com/OKrgz) out. It generates like: `Array( [0] => 2     [1] => 4     [2] => 5     [3] => 6     [4] => 7     [5] => 9     [6] => 10 )`

Comment: Ah you mean the result is sorted? Yes, that may be true, but not a real problem. One could [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/function.shuffle.php) the input/output array to get an unsorted result.

Answer (score 10):

- Create an array from 1 to 10 ([range](http://nl2.php.net/range)).
- Put it in random order
  ([shuffle](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)).
- Select 7 items from the array ([array_slice](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php))

Comment: Instead of the second 2 steps, use `array_rand(array, 7)`

Answer (score 5):

Populate an array with ten elements (the numbers one through ten), shuffle the array, and remove the first (or last) three elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [comments in the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), there are several solutions for this.

An easy one is this one:

```
$min = 1;
$max = 10;
$total = 7;
$rand = array();
while (count($rand) < $total ) {
    $r = mt_rand($min,$max);
    if (!in_array($r,$rand)) $rand[] = $r;
}
```

Comment: Not very efficient, but easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Whole numbers?  Well, if you want 7 out of 10 then you more efficiently DON'T want 3 out of 10.

Feel free to use any of the other responses but instead of creating 7 numbers start with 10 and eliminate 3.  That will tend to speed things up by more than double.

Answer (score 0):

The "shuffle" method has a MAJOR FALW. When the numbers are big, shuffle 3 billion indexs will instantly CAUSE 500 error. Here comes a best solution for really big numbers.

```
function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $total) {
    $temp_arr = array();
    while(sizeof($temp_arr) < $total) $temp_arr[rand($min, $max)] = true;
    return $temp_arr;
}
```

Say I want to get 10 unique random numbers from 1 billion to 4 billion.

```
$random_numbers = getRandomNumbers(1000000000,4000000000,10);
```

PS: Execution time: 0.027 microseconds