# How would this short this is php code?

Tags: php, short

```
$szam[1]=rand(1,95);
$szam[2]=rand(1,95);

if($szam[1]!=$szam[2]){
$szam[3]=rand(1,95);

    if($szam[3]!=$szam[2]and $szam[3]!=$szam[1]){
    $szam[4]=rand(1,95);

        if($szam[4]!=$szam[3]and$szam[4]!=$szam[2]and$szam[4]!=$szam[1]){
        $szam[5]=rand(1,95);

            if($szam[5]!=$szam[4]and$szam[5]!=$szam[3]and$szam[5]!=$szam[2]and$szam[5]!=$szam[1]){
                $lottoszam=$szam[1].",".$szam[2].",".$szam[3].",".$szam[4].",".$szam[5];
            }
            else{$szam[5]=rand(1,95);}
        }
        else{$szam[4]=rand(1,95);}
    }
    else{$szam[3]=rand(1,95);}
}
else{$szam[2]=rand(1,95);}
```

Comment: Change the variable `$szam` to `$s`. Boom, shorter code!

Comment: This question is too vague. What do you mean by `short this php code`? Tell us what this code is doing, and why you want it shorter.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792816/php-unique-random-numbers - trying to find random unique numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using in_array()  function. [PHP Manual in_array() funcion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Save your random numbers in array and check it like this

```
if (in_array($random, $numbers)) {
  //exist
}
```