# PHP unique number in array

Tags: php

I am trying to generate 6 numbers in an array, I'm using the mt_rand function, however I can't have the same number in the array. How would I go about checking for this and generating the number again?

I've thought about making a duplicate array and looping throw and counting how many are in the array, if its more then 1 then re generating the numbers and checking again, however this just seems like a lot of work for something that php might have a native function for that I can't find...

The duplicate thing isn't what I need help with, that is checking the key to the value, I need all values to be unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate array of random unique numbers in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824770/generate-array-of-random-unique-numbers-in-php)

Comment: This isn't the same thing, that is to make sure the key and value aren't the same. I need just values.

Comment: This one most certainly is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792816/php-unique-random-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this question is not a duplicate of the second question that @Laurel posted, please provide more information to explain how it is different. Also, to make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code to show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), preferably in the form of a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number_of_numbers = 6;//number_of_numbers in array
$min = 1;//minimum value of number that you want
$max = 15;//maximum value of number that you want

$array = array();
for ($a = 0; $a < $number_of_numbers; $a++) {
    $check = 0;//for entering while loop
    while ($check !== false) { //pick a number and check if it is in array if it is in the array, pick again and check again
        $try[$a] = mt_rand($min, $max); //pick a number
        $check = array_search($try[$a], $array);// search that number if it is in the array
    }
    $array[] = $try[$a]; //add number to array
}
var_dump($array); // show me the array
```

Is that what you mean? I may get misunderstood about the array keys. Can you explain it a little more?

here is the output. sorry i forgot to add it first.

```
array(6) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> int(12) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(5) [4]=> int(9) [5]=> int(15) }
```